# How to navigate one page to another page using React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

my scenario, I am trying to navigate `login.js` page to `home.js` page. I need to implement `navigation` but need to hide into login.js but need to show into home.js. Here, login button click to navigate home page. The navigation should support iOS and Android both platform.how to achieve this?

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Login from './components/Login';

export default class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Login/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Login.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
    state = {
       isLoading: false 
    };

    showLoader = () => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    };

    // Login Click Action
    loginclick = () => {
        //this.showLoader();
        console.log('Login Clicked...'); // Need to move home page
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={(this.loginclick)}>
                    <Text style={styles.btntext}>Sing In</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.activityview, styles.horizontal}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" animating={this.state.isLoading} color='#fff' />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**Package.json**

```
   {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.5",
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^1.6.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html) for moving different screens.

Change your `App.js` as below in order to handle navigation

```
import React from "react";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Home from "import your home component";

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: Login,
    Home: Home
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Login"
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

After that, you can handle navigation to `Home` from `Login` changing your `loginclick` function as below

```
loginclick = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: I am getting error `Unable to resolve "react-navigation-stack" from "App.js"`

Comment: you need to install ```npm install react-navigation```

Comment: again I am getting error `TypeError: (0, _reactNavigation. (In'(0, _reactNavigation.createAppContainer) (RootStack)','(0, _reactNavigation.createAppContainer)' is undefined)`

Comment: try ```npm install react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view```

Comment: I did but again showing same error in mobile. FYI: i am doing expo project.

Comment: try to follow the guideline provided by react-navigation - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

Comment: if you still getting the same error after you follow above guidelines, please share your ```package.json```

Comment: @mobileapps update your react-navigation version. react-navigation-stack not supported for earlier versions. replace react-navigation version in your package.json with this ```"react-navigation": "^4.0.10"``` then run ```npm install```